# MySQL error 1064 (4200) With Every Query

Tags: mysql

I have recieved the following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
```

for every type of query I have entered. I have tried the following queries and received that error

```
SELECT * FROM finger-dodge-statistics.activity-open-statistics;

select * from 'activity-open-statistics';

INSERT INTO activity-open-statistics (time, user-id, api, activity-name) VALUES (1432214612444, 0, 3, 'com.edr.MainActivity');
```

Comment: The dash character is not a standard character in a MySQL identifier. If you want to use non-standard characters, the identifiers must be escaped. The normative pattern for that in MySQL is to enclose the identifier in backticks. This allows you to use an identifier that contains spaces, dashes, etc. (NOTE: If `sql_mode` includes `ANSI_QUOTES`, then you could use double quotes (in place of backticks) to enclose identifiers.

Comment: If you could post your mysql version, database name (is it finger...?), and table schema that might help people troubleshoot with you. You might also look at the documentation on mysql's web site to see where you're going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `,

```
SELECT * FROM `finger-dodge-statistics`.`activity-open-statistics`;
```

Comment: In this case are the back ticks ` needed because mySQL tries to do math on field name activity minus open minus statistics?